# cannot understand why deleting content of a list will delete also the content of the list from which it originates (Python)

Tags: python

I fail to understand one of the result of this code – and especially what should I do as a "workaround":

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a

print (a)    # >> gives [1, 2, 3]    # >> expected
print (b)    # >> gives [1, 2, 3]    # >> expected

b.clear()

print (a)    # >> gives []    # >> ??
print (b)    # >> gives []    # >> expected
```

Q1: Why is `a` also cleared ?

Q2: What should I do if I want to keep `a` as a sort of "template", so that, once set, do operations/modifications only on copies of it, without care about affecting the "original" in any way ?

(happens the same if `a` is a dictionary; happens the same if using `del b[:]` instead of `b.clear()`)

Comment: You didn't make a copy, you only created an additional reference. See the duplicate on how to properly copy a list.

Comment: b=a only passes the reference of a to b; which means b and a both really point to the same list.

Any operation you do on a will also be reflected upon b.

To make b independent of a, you need to deep copy a so... b= list(a). Then all your changes to b and a will be independent

Comment: Well, now I see the q/a there. That question uses other words and this is why I didn't found it using my own. What should I do now with my question ? Delete it ?